# Can anyone identify the worm in this video clip?

Tags: zoology, species-identification

My wife came across this youtube clip of a spider and a [worm](http://youtu.be/4E5vUUtSWT4). Can anyone identify at least the phylum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a Gordian worm or more accurately known as *Spinochordodes tellinii* . Good music for a parasitic event like that by the way. Nematomorpha is the phylum.

[image]

If your a molecular guy, check out *Spinochordodes tellinii* and the WNT pathway, pretty cool stuff.